# Incrementing Click Redux Function in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, svg, redux

I am working with some svg elements and i have built an increment button.

The increment button takes the the `path d` values converts it into an array and sums `5` from the third element of the array. If the element is `'L'` or `'M'` it does nothing

Here the click function in the redux, it takes the values of the incrementing action state

```
  const a = action.index;
  let string = state[a].d;
```

It converts in an array

```
let array = string.split(" ");
```

and then it does all the calculation i said in the loop

See the full redux function

```
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'INCREMENT_COORDINATES' :
      console.log("incrementing coordinaates")
      const a = action.index;
      let string = state[a].d;
      let array = string.split(" ");
      let max = array.length;
      let i = 3;
      let click = () => {
        i++;
        if ( i === max ) i = 3;
        if (array[i] !== 'M' && array[i] !== 'L') array[i] = parseInt(array[i]) + 5;
        array.join(' ');
      };
      return [
        ...state.slice(0,a), // before the one we are updating
        {...state[a], d: click()}, // updating the with the click function
        ...state.slice(a + 1), // after the one we are updating
      ]
    default:
      return state;
  }
```

See the video demo while i debug it http://www.fastswf.com/uSBU68E

As you can see the code does the right calculation and it sums `5` from the fourth element and it is returning the number `331`. So all good!But the problem is that i need to return it as `'331'`, a new element of the array to continue the loop.

I have built a demo which is perfectly working and doing what i want to achieve, using the same code! So i don't understand what i am doing wrong when i apply it in my redux function.

See the [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/tumesug/edit?js,console,output) perfectly working as i want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDITED:

1. Your `click` function doesn't return any value, so `array.join(' ')` result isn't assigned anywhere and property `d` remains unassigned.

   ```
   let click = () => {
     i++;
     if ( i === max ) i = 3;
     if (array[i] !== 'M' && array[i] !== 'L') array[i] = parseInt(array[i]) + 5;
     return array.join(' '); 
   };
   ```
2. Each time increment_coordinates action is invoked, whole code in block after `case 'INCREMENT_COORDINATES' :` is executed. In this case important is that variable `i` is in each call a new variable, initialized with 3. During execution of `click` function, `i` increases to 4 and then it goes out of it's scope so its value is lost. 
   My suggestion is to include current index in `state` (hope this would work & I've removed `click` function as it's each call re-created and only once invoked)
   Remember to include index also in line where you pass your coordinates for the first time to your reducer or check whether `state[a]` contains property `index` and set `i=3` if not.

   ```
   switch(action.type) {
   case 'INCREMENT_COORDINATES' :
     console.log("incrementing coordinaates")
     const a = action.index;
     let string = state[a].d;
     let array = string.split(" ");
     let max = array.length;
     let i = (state[a].index || 3) + 1;
     if ( i === max ) i = 3;
     if (array[i] !== 'M' && array[i] !== 'L') array[i] = parseInt(array[i]) + 5;
     return [
       ...state.slice(0,a), // before the one we are updating
       {...state[a], d: array.join(' '); index: i}, // updating 
       ...state.slice(a + 1), // after the one we are updating
     ]
   default:
     return state;
   }
   ```

Comment: Yes converting the number into the string is not my problem, so then what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Now I see that your function `click` doesn't return any value, hence `d` has no value in updated item. Switch its last line to `return array.join(' ');`. Does it fix your problem?

Comment: correct, this is the purpose of array.join(' ') in the click function, to paste the new values in the d path, at the moment it seems ignored, where you mean to last line? update the answer to accept it

Comment: isn't also your `i` set to 3 with each call of increment? consider storing it as a property of your state object

Comment: answer almost correct!, it is now only incrementing the 3 element

Comment: Yes, because each time you invoke increment action, all these variables defined with keyword `let` are created. In this case `let i=3` causes this issue. It would be better to change your state object to something like `{array: arrayOfCoordinates, currentIndex: i}`

Comment: can you pls update the answer, not totally clear to me, i was trying to do a map now

Comment: i was debugging it and this is what  let i = state[a].index + 1 returns "[object Object]1"

Comment: Have you initialized property index with 3? Remove for a while "+1" and see what value is in state[a].index

Comment: let i = state[a].index returns i = undefined state = [Object, Object, Object, Object], a = 0, yes i have also initialized with 3 but with no luck

Comment: Add console.log(JSON.stringify(state)). How did you try initializing it?

Comment: Or make `let i = (state[a].index || 3) + 1;`