# Conditional functions in Redux state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, redux

I have built an incrementing button to increase the string ( summing 20 to each number starting from n 3 ) in the `path d` for `SVG` elements.

The increment button does the following in my reduce function and it works fine

```
export default function svgs(state = [], action) {
  switch(action.type) {
      case 'INCREMENT_COORDINATES' :
        console.log("incrementing coordinaates");
        const a = action.index;
        let string = state[a].d;
        let array = string.split(" ");
        let max = array.length;
        let last = max - 2;
        let i = (state[a].index || 3) + 1;
        if ( i === last ) i = 3;
        if (array[i] !== 'M' && array[i] !== 'L') array[i] = parseInt(array[i]) + 20;
        return [
          ...state.slice(0,a), // before the one we are updating
          {...state[a], d: array.join(' '), index: i}, // updating
          ...state.slice(a + 1), // after the one we are updating
        ]
      default:
        return state;
  }
}
```

My struggle is that in the SVG component the `path d` can consume also different data objects

For example

apart from

```
path d={svg.d}
```

it can also have

```
path d={svg.d2}
path d={svg.d3}
```

See the snippet example

```
<svg>
  <svg>
    <g>
      <path d={svg.d}></path>
    </g>
  </svg>
  <g>
    <path d={svg.d2}></path>
    <path d={svg.d3}></path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

How can I modify my redux function to increment only the string or strings of that particular `SVG` element

I have some svg elements which can have all svg objects ( `svg.d, svg.d2, svg.d3`), or only two ( `svg.d, svg.d2` ) or one ( `svg.d` ).

For example, if I modify that redux function above, it can be something like

```
let string = state[a].d || state[a].d2 || state[a].d3;
```

and then

```
return [
  ...state.slice(0,a), // before the one we are updating
  {...state[a], d: array.join(' '), index: i, d2: array.join(' '), index: i, d3: array.join(' '), index: i }, // updating
  ...state.slice(a + 1), // after the one we are updating
]
```

The only problem here is that if one of the SVG elements has one or two empty objects between `svg.d`, `svg.d2`, `svg.d3`, after the click action it gets the same values of the string modified, and I do not want this.

Hope explanation is clear, I will set up a jsBin if it is necessary.

Comment: What do you mean by the following: "...if one of the svg elements has one or two empty objects between `svg.d`, `svg.d2`, `svg.d3`..."?

Comment: What have you tried? Your code is almost the same as [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42179256/incrementing-click-redux-function-in-an-array/) in your previous question (only variable `last` added)

Comment: setup the jsBin

Answer (score 1):

You could map over the svg objects and transform them individually (if they exist):

```
const aObj = state[a];
const [d, d2, d3] = [aObj.d, aObj.d2, aObj.d3].map((string) => {
    if(!string) return null;
    let array = string.split(" ");
    let max = array.length;
    let last = max - 2;
    let i = (state[a].index || 3) + 1;
    if ( i === last ) i = 3;
    if (array[i] !== 'M' && array[i] !== 'L') array[i] = parseInt(array[i]) + 20;
    return array.join(" ");
  });


return [
  ...state.slice(0,a), // before the one we are updating
  {...aObj, d, d2, d3}, // updating
  ...state.slice(a + 1), // after the one we are updating
]
```

I'm not sure I completely understand the question though.

Comment: answer almost perfect, you understood well, the only problem here is that mapping the string duplicates the element

Comment: @Koala7 Duplicates what element?

Comment: It create a new element with the string modified instead of modifying the element itself. See the video http://www.fastswf.com/IdNwlBo

Comment: Basically i need a replace of the string of the element

Comment: @Koala7 Redux is based on the principle that the state is immutable, so it won't happen, and even if you can, it is not a good pattern. Replacing the current state by a slightly modified copy is ok. Or is your state that enormous? Then it should be handled in the backend probably.

Comment: is it a good practice handling the state in his component? You arise a good point because sometimes i am not sure where i have to handle the states